# Android Table Layout error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/">
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Execution Time"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_column="1" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_column="7"
            android:text="118161.4 ms" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Memory"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_column="1" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_column="7" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CPU"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_column="1" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_column="7" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have used TableLayout.But when I try to run the code I get this error

`Error:(8, 18) Resource id cannot be an empty string (at 'id' with value '@+id/')`.

As I am new to android .Kindly help me in this regard.

Comment: Just remove that line `android:id="@+id/"`

Comment: either remove or give some name like : android:id="@+id/layout_tableLayout"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your `RelativeLayout` and `TableLayout` have the following attribute:

```
android:id="@+id/"
```

This is incomplete. From the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource.html#idvalue):

> For the ID value, you should usually use this syntax form: `"@+id/name"`. The plus symbol, `+`, indicates that this is a new resource ID and the `aapt` tool will create a new resource integer in the `R.java` class, if it doesn't already exist.

In other words, change every occurrence above to something in the form of `"@+id/name"`. For example:

```
<RelativeLayout ... android:id="@+id/root">
```

And:

```
<TableLayout ... android:id="@+id/table">
```

Or, if you don't need to refer to the individual items, just remove the id attribute all together.

Answer (score 0):

Error is you are specifying android:id but not giving valid id

```
android:id="@+id/"
```

so if you want to give id you have give id as

```
android:id="@+id/<control_id>"
```

`<control_id>` is some valid string using which you will refer control in java code as well as inside layout.

so if you do not want to give any id then simply remove `android:id="@+id/"` attribute of widget from layout.xml.

Comment: @SyedNazarMuhammad To answer a question, use the Answer function. The comments are there to comment on the question, e.g. if something is unclear etc.